# Add class to active menu on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

When I click a parent menu (like Domains), it shows it's children, when I click one of them (like, My Domains), the page reloads with the parent menu closed (not expanded, as the image bellow)

The classes are "active" for menu active (blue background) and "open" for visible children

[image: Bug]

These are the JS codes:

```
  // Handle clicking on the naviagtion dropdown items
  jQuery('.navbar .toggle > a').click(function() {
    if (!jQuery(this).next().is(":visible")) {
      jQuery('.toggle a').removeClass('open');
      jQuery('.toggle ul:visible').hide();
    }
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('open');
    jQuery(this).next().slideToggle();
  });

  // Tabs Changer
  // ===============================
    //Default Action
    jQuery(".tab-content").hide(); //Hide all content
    if (jQuery(location).attr('hash').substr(1)!="") {
        var activeTab = jQuery(location).attr('hash');
        jQuery("ul").find('li').removeClass('open');
        jQuery("ul.nav li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        jQuery(activeTab+"nav").addClass("active");
        jQuery(activeTab).show();
    } else {
        jQuery("#tabs ul.nav .nav-tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
        jQuery(".tab-content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
    }

    //On Click Event
    jQuery("#tabs ul.nav li").click(function() {
        jQuery("ul").find('li').removeClass('open');
        jQuery("ul.nav li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        jQuery(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        var activeTab = jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        if (activeTab.substr(0,1)=="#" && activeTab.substr(1)!="") { //Determine if a tab or link
            jQuery(".tab-content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
            jQuery(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
            return false;
        } else {
            return true; // If link allow redirect
        }
    });

});
```

Click Login to see a live example of the menu:
https://whmcsdesigns.com/demo/clientarea.php?action=domains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the page and enter the following, in the console, you will see that it works as you expect:

```
jQuery(".navbar .toggle.active > .nav-link").addClass('open'); 
jQuery(".navbar .toggle.active > ul").css('display', 'block');
```

However, you may run into some timing issues with this. It's not the best practice, to wrap it in `jQuery(window).on`, however it will get the job done:

```
jQuery(window).on('load', null, {}, function () { 
    jQuery(".navbar .toggle.active > .nav-link").addClass('open'); 
    jQuery(".navbar .toggle.active > ul").css('display', 'block'); 
});
```

Normally, it should run synchronously, but for the sake of getting it to work, using `window.onload` will run this code when everything is finished loading, where we can safely *assume* that your menu will be ready to accept this code. So this may run much later (we're talking milliseconds), after the menu is initially setup up and ready for this code.

Answer (score 0):

use  **[event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)**

```
  // Handle clicking on the naviagtion dropdown items
      jQuery('.navbar .toggle > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        if (!jQuery(this).next().is(":visible")) {
          jQuery('.toggle a').removeClass('open');
          jQuery('.toggle ul:visible').hide();
        }
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('open');
        jQuery(this).next().slideToggle();
      });
```

reference **[event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)**

Comment: e.preventDefault(); and use e.stopPropagation(); also

Comment: Like this? "event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();" Still a no go :/

Comment: I've started learning javascript last week, so I'm not sure. There's a link right above for a live version of the menu, maybe you would like to take a look?

Comment: It's being called in a separate javascript file - You want it full?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38065/discussion-between-user2056484-and-rituraj-ratan)

Comment: you got your answer  i think as above my answer

Answer (score 0):

in CSS you can show/hide div when menu item is active